# How to Mock YearMonth in java 8

Tags: java, unit-testing, datetime, mocking, mockito

I am trying to mock out `YearMonth.class` with mockito.

I am calling the `getYear` and `getMonth` methods, so I want to control what values are used within the method I am testing. However I am encouuntering the following issue.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class java.time.YearMonth
Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
  - final classes
  - anonymous classes
  - primitive types
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl$1.withBefores(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

The test has the following definition for the mock

```
YearMonth yearMonthMock = mock(YearMonth.class);
```

And the method I am testing has the following

```
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
String year = Integer.toString(yearMonth.getYear());
String month = Integer.toString(yearMonth.getMonthValue());
```

How can I resolve the exception to continue to work with `YearMonth.class` or should I use an alternate approach.

Comment: Why you can't use directly YearMonth? Why you need to mock it?

Comment: What are you trying to test? If you want `yearMonth.getYear()` to return a specific year you can always use it directly without any mocking - `YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.of(2016,11);`

Answer (score 3):

Accessing date time specific functionality via static methods are tricky. You are trying to mock a static method that is dependent on the system clock. This makes it difficult to mock/spy without taking some drastic measures. (like changing the time on the system. lol)

One way around this could be to abstract the access to that functionality behind an interface you can control.

```
public interface YearMonthProvider {
    YearMonth now(ZoneId zone);
}
```

implementation in production could look like this

```
public class SystemYearMonth implements YearMonthProvider {
    public YearMonth now(ZoneId zone) {
        return YearMonth.now(zone);
    }
}
```

The method under test would depend on the abstraction rather than the concretion

```
public class MyClass {
    private YearMonthProvider clock;

    public MyClass(YearMonthProvider clock) {
        this.clock = clock;
    }

    public void MyMethod(){
        //...other code

        YearMonth yearMonth = clock.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        String year = Integer.toString(yearMonth.getYear());
        String month = Integer.toString(yearMonth.getMonthValue());

        //... other code
    }
}
```

This now allows for the flexibility to swap out the dependency as needed.

In a Test

```
//Arrange
YearMonth yearMonthStub = YearMonth.of(2016,11);
YearMonthProvider yearMonthMock = mock(YearMonthProvider.class);
when(yearMonthMock.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"))).thenReturn(yearMonthStub);

MyClass sut = new MyClass(yearMonthMock);

//Act
sut.MyMethod();

//Assert
//...
```